# Can I use the _destroy attribute in a non-nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have something like this in my controller:

```
FacultyMembership.update(params[:faculty_memberships].keys,
                         params[:faculty_memberships].values)
```

and whenever the `_destroy` key in `params[:faculty_memberships].values` is true, the record is destroyed.

Is there something like this in rails? I realize there are other ways of doing this, I was just curious if something like this existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

no!

**Long answer**

Still no! It is true that it works on [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

> If you want to destroy the associated model through the attributes
>   hash, you have to enable it first using the :allow_destroy option.
>   Now, when you add the _destroy key to the attributes hash, with a
>   value that evaluates to true, you will destroy the associated model.

But why not trying it out in the console:

```
?> bundle exec rails c
?> m = MyModel.create attr_1: "some_value", attr_2: "some_value"
?> m.update(_destroy: '1') # or _destroy: true
?> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute '_destroy' for MyModel
```

This is because the [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) implementation is the following:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb, line 245
def update(attributes)
  # The following transaction covers any possible database side-effects of the
  # attributes assignment. For example, setting the IDs of a child collection.
  with_transaction_returning_status do
    assign_attributes(attributes)
    save
  end
end
```

and the source for [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) is:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb, line 23
def assign_attributes(new_attributes)
  if !new_attributes.respond_to?(:stringify_keys)
    raise ArgumentError, "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument."
  end
  return if new_attributes.blank?

  attributes                  = new_attributes.stringify_keys
  multi_parameter_attributes  = []
  nested_parameter_attributes = []

  attributes = sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes)

  attributes.each do |k, v|
    if k.include?("(")
      multi_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
    elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
      nested_parameter_attributes << [ k, v ]
    else
      _assign_attribute(k, v)
    end
  end

  assign_nested_parameter_attributes(nested_parameter_attributes) unless nested_parameter_attributes.empty?
  assign_multiparameter_attributes(multi_parameter_attributes) unless multi_parameter_attributes.empty?
end
```

Comment: Ah well. It would have been a pretty nifty feature imo.

Comment: Rails is all about REST. So if you want to remove a record you will use [`DELETE`](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) which is mapped to the `destroy` method of your controller. That's why!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
class FacultyMembership < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :_destroy

  def _destroy= value
    self.destroy if value.present?
  end  
end
```

Possibly this can break nested forms with destroy - didn't check.